# Iphone -> How i can simulate click on javascript action?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, nsurl

i try to simulate a clic on a "javascript:void(0)"; Because i need html data in this script

But how i can do this?

I work only with NSUrl (and I don't won't use illegal API like UITouchEvent)

Thx for all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what it is you're trying to do, but assuming that you are trying to do this within a UIWebView then you can do this:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE"];
```

You can then execute any javascript that you liken the page

Hope this helps :)